# UINavigationController title is not displayed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have normal UIViewController ,inwhich I added UINavigationControllerDelegate,i
added as following in willappear?but it did not work?

```
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.title = @"hai";
```

Answer (score 46):

You should set the title in the view controller you add to your navigation controller.

i.e. in the add view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"My Title";
}
```

or access the array of your viewcontrollers directly

```
        AddFriendViewController *addFriendsView = [[AddFriendViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddFriendViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:addFriendsView animated:YES];
        [[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] setTitle:@"myTitle"];
        [addFriendsView release];
```

Answer (score 22):

Every view controller has a navigation item. You are changing the navigation item of the navigation controller... but that will never be seen unless the navigation controller was inside another navigation controller! Instead of

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.title = @"hai";
```

you want

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"hai";
```

or, if your navigation item's title is nil, the navigation controller will use your view controller's title:

```
self.title = @"hai";
```

You should simply set the view title, which is used by both navigation bars and tab bars, unless you want to specify a different title for each of those for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `self.navigationController.navigationItem` is not `nil` when you set its title?

Answer (score 0):

If no viewcontroller has been pushed on the stack, ie. you're displaying the viewcontroller at the top of the stack (sometimes called rootViewController) you can do it with

```
[rootViewController setTitle:@"Title"];
```

NOTE that you must use **setTitle** - rootViewController.title=@"Title" will normally not work.

Actually, you can do it with any viewcontroller, even if it's not viewDidLoad'ed yet. If it's created programmatically, just create it with

```
myViewController *mvc=[[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nameofnibwithout.xib" bundle:nil];
```

Or you could declare it as an object in the app delegate, make it an IBOutlet, create a UIViewController and set its class to myViewController, and connect it to the IBOutlet so it's not nil.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the Navigation bar to "Black Navigation Bar With Prompt" in the Attributes tab on the controller. That's what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the title was not visible on `iOS6`, when I set it up in the `init` method:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {
        self.title = LS(@"Favorites");
        self.tabBarItem.title = LS(@"Favorites");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star"];
    }

    return self;
}
```

So, it should be moved from there to `ViewDidLoad`.